# How to deploy Next.js app with ssl without nginx

Tags: next.js, deployment

We are in the process of deploying the app with Next.js.
Instead of using web hosting such as Vercel or github pages, we will deploy using our own cloud (our own VM server, not aws ec2). Since we are using Next.js SSR, I understood that static hosting does not support SSR by just building it like the way of building and deploying CSR method(like pointing static files in cloudfront or s3 bucket etc).

If so, is it correct that deploying using CDN also can't use SSR features??
If correct, what is the way to run the Nextjs app as `pm2 start` when you deploy it, and apply the ssl certificate to enable https connection while maintaining the SSR? Should I think of redirecting using LB of my cloud where my app is running?

By the way, NginX is not available for now. So could you suggest another options?
I searched for lots of solutions, but still i feel confused.